How can I get rid of rounded screen corners?
I have a Pixel 7a running Android 13, Magisk Rooted, and PixelBlaster-OS custom ROM. I want to remove the rounding on the corner of the screen.
Even after issuing the command su settings put secure sysui_rounded_size 1, the top-left and right of my lock screen is still prone to this software corner curving:

Screenshot resized. Click to see the full image.
How can I get rid of rounded screen corners?
